# Django authentication with curl and C++

Tags: c++, django, authentication, curl

I'm trying to create a C++ application to login in a Django server. I've been looking for this but I haven't found a solution to my specific question.

I'm using one of the examples of libcurl website to do the request:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void)
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://127.0.0.1/");

        /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */ 
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        /* Check for errors */ 
        if(res != CURLE_OK)
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));

        /* always cleanup */ 
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And I've found an option to put user and password:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "luis:123456");
```

But the problem is that I don't know how Django can recognise this curl option.

Other posibility would be to complete the form that Django provides to login. The form that I'm using is:

```
<html><body>
<form method="post" action="/login">
{% csrf_token %}
  {% if form.errors %}
    <p class="error">Login error</p>
  {% endif %}
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Username</td>
    <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Password</td>
    <td>{{ form.password }}</td>
</tr>
</table>

<input type="submit" value="login" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

With this option, my problem is that I don't know how get and complete the form using C++ and curl.

Comment: do you have access to the django code or is it a black box for you? because you could create a new django view that accepts username and password as get parameters (and possibly some kind of custom authentication token for your c++ application) and logs the user in and hit that view with curl.

Comment: yes, the django server is mine. I did a test sending my user and pass in the url, and the view had implemented a custom authentication. It works but its not secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to send a POST request with the login form data to the login URL - unless the Django web-application provides a different login mechanism which is usually not the case.

When you send the POST data and the Django login form processing did successfully authenticate the user you'll get back a cookie that you'd to store and use in the subsequent requests.

Also note that the login form uses the `csrf_token` tags which means if you don't send a `csrftoken` cookie and a token with the form data with your request, Django will reject the request. I'd suggest you take a look at the HTTP request a browser does when you load and submit the login page. All modern browsers have nice debug tools to monitor the requests.

Alternatively, in case you have control over the Django web-application, you can disable the CSRF token validation in the view function for the login page.

Comment: I have control over the Django web-application. How I can disable the CSRF token? Is that secure?

Comment: There is a decorator `django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt` which you can add to your login view. For the login I'd say it's not critical to remove it as CSRF exploits often require you are already logged in. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery for details. Also check out the Django documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf.

Comment: Thanks. Using curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "username=luis&password=123456"); and disable the CSRF, I could login in django server. Can I hide the POST options? Because if I examine the request with wireshark, I can see the user and password and I think that it's not safe.

Comment: No, you can't. HTTP is a plain text protocol, you'd need to use HTTPS if you want a secure communication.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure, but I think what CURL does is the standard [HTTP authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). It doesn't know that a form is a login-form.

Comment: Thats right - I wonder if he could craft the POST from the form to login however

Comment: Yes, but I don't know if it's possible that Django recognise that authentication

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest ways to see what is happening is to install wireshark, look at the data and use that to engineer your curl options.

Comment: Line-based text data: application/x-www-form-urlencoded: csrfmiddlewaretoken=SqoFeTva84MUjmgDAvkuRWb9zL83UDsf&username=luis&password=123456

Answer (score 0):

*As stated by the original poster of the question:*

---

**Solution**

To realize a POST with curl c++, I have used `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "username=luis&password=123456);` and, in Django web-service views, I disable CSRF:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
...
@csrf_exempt
def mylogin(request):

    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
           login(request, user)
        else:
            # Return a 'disabled account' error message
            return HttpResponse("Error\n")
    else:
        # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
        return HttpResponse("Invalid pass or user\n")
...
```